# Has James Bond ever slept with a woman who was drunk or otherwise unable to give consent in the way we accept today?

Tags: james-bond

I recently came across [this Austin Powers meme on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/comments/16leycm/austin_powers/):

[image: 2 panel comic depicting a scene from Austin Powers: The Spy who Shagged Me, first panel: Vanessa Kensington is clearly drunk and hovering over Austin Powers in a lavish bedroom, ordering him: "Kiss me". Second panel: Austin powers turns away his face and gently pushes Vanessa aside, saying: "I can't darling. You're drunk it's not right". Caption below the comic: tumblr user pomelomela writes: "Even the most sexed up man in all of history knew that taking advantage of a woman was never ok."]

The discussion below the meme mentioned James Bond and how Austin Powers parodies him and his films. I was wondering whether James Bond has acted differently when faced with the same situation in one of his films. Specifically, the situation of a woman who in modern western culture would be considered unable to consent approaching him with sexual intent, only for Bond to happily agree and sleep with her instead of refusing to take advantage of her like Austin Powers did in this scene.

And yes, I know that James Bond, especially early on, was a relic of a different age and that we shouldn't blindly apply modern standards to those days, but I'm still curious about this.

Comment: The books are decidedly problematic https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/news/james-bond-ian-fleming-censored-edits-b2290277.html

Answer (score 9):

Two scenes that some consider offensive (women weren't drunk but today one might say they didn't exactly consent):

From *Goldfinger* (1964):

([Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SwVqDeoK4g) in case above doesn't show)

From *Thunderball* (1965):

One writer on the Goldfinger scene ([2021](https://theithacan.org/41909/life-culture/popped-culture/column-legacy-of-james-bond-is-polluted-by-misogyny/)):

> “Goldfinger” was my first Bond movie. For many people, it would understandably be their last. The film features a horrific scene at the end where Bond — who at the time of the film’s 1964 release was played by Sean Connery — forces himself on a woman in a barn. Bond pins her on the floor and forces her to kiss him, despite obvious verbal and visual cues that she wants him off her. Her name? Pussy Galore.

> The first time I watched “Goldfinger” with my dad, I was a preteen. However, it was also his first time since his childhood when he last saw the movie. Having forgotten about the barn scene but seeing where it was going, he got up and skipped the scene. I thanked him for doing that recently. When I revisited “Goldfinger” years later, the scene disturbed me, as I hope it would for anybody reading this.

Cary Fukunaga on the Thunderball scene, (*Hollywood Reporter*, [2021](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-features/bond-director-cary-fukunaga-no-time-to-die-1235017724/)):

> “Is it Thunderball or Goldfinger where, like, basically Sean Connery’s character rapes a woman?” Fukunaga asks. “She’s like ‘No, no, no,’ and he’s like, ‘Yes, yes, yes.’ That wouldn’t fly today.”

See also: